# Why am I getting this error while trying to retrieve data from MySQL db using bash script in Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, database-connection

I am trying to retrieve email address from MySQL database.

```
#!/bin/bash
MYSQLHOST="192.168.1.1"                                               
MYSQLDB="nuni"
MYSQLUSER="root"
MYSQLPASS="rootpass"
MYSQLOPTS="--user=${MYSQLUSER} --password=${MYSQLPASS} --host=${MYSQLHOST} ${MYSQLDB}"
EMAIL=echo "SELECT email FROM Edsrn WHERE userid = 1235" | mysql ${MYSQLOPTS}
echo "E-mail: $EMAIL"
```

What is wrong with it? I says "command not found". Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the `-e` parameter to evaluate SQL statements instead. This should be what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYSQLHOST="192.168.1.1"                                               
MYSQLDB="nuni"
MYSQLUSER="root"
MYSQLPASS="rootpass"
MYSQLOPTS="-s --user=${MYSQLUSER} --password=${MYSQLPASS} --host=${MYSQLHOST} ${MYSQLDB}  -e "
EMAIL=$(mysql ${MYSQLOPTS} "SELECT email FROM Edsrn WHERE userid = 1235" | tail -n 1)
echo "E-mail: $EMAIL"
```

Note the `tail` is needed since the output from mysql looks like this:

```
column
value
```

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to run `"SELECT email FROM Edsrn WHERE userid = 1235"` with `$EMAIL` set to "echo". If you wanted the result of your command to be put in `$EMAIL` then you got the syntax wrong.

```
EMAIL=$(echo "SELECT email FROM Edsrn WHERE userid = 1235" | mysql ${MYSQLOPTS})
```

Also, [BASH FAQ entry #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).